# Selenium WebDriver error acentuação

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou usando o Selenium WebDriver para realiar teste com python

ao executar esta linha:

```
mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text.encode('utf-8')
```

Tenho como resposta:

```
{'descricao': 'PROTOCOLIZADA PETI\xc3\x87\xc3\x83O'},
```

Quando deveria:

```
{'descricao': 'PROTOCOLIZADA PETIÇÃO'},
```

**Codigo completo**

```
#encoding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from app.browser_automation.browser_automation import BrowserAutomation
import time
import CONST
from datetime import datetime

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class BrowserAutomationTrt19(BrowserAutomation):

    def page_is_loaded(self, driver):
        time.sleep(2)
        return True #driver.find_element_by_id("Div_HeaderMedium") != None

    # consultas dos processo  na base afim de procurar no portal
    def make_consulta(self, numero):

        #preencher os elementos da consulta
        #dividir os numero em array
        partes_numero_processo = self.get_partes_do_numero(numero)

        #preencher os campos no formulario da página

        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'seq')]").send_keys(partes_numero_processo[0])
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'dig')]").send_keys(partes_numero_processo[1])
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'ano')]").send_keys(partes_numero_processo[2])
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'org')]").send_keys(partes_numero_processo[5])

        #clicar no butão buscar
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@class,'btnBuscar')]").click()
        #atualizar tela
        self.browser.refresh

        #se nao encontrar processo
        #if not self.processo_naoencontrado():
            #wait = ui.WebDriverWait(self.browser, 1000000000)
        #else:
            #CONST.PROCESSO_ENCONTRADO = False

        return True

    #se nao encontra processo
    def processo_naoencontrado(self):

        try:
            return "Nenhum registro encontrado!" in self.browser.find_element_by_id('idDivBlocoMensagem').text
        except:
            return False

    #obtendo as movimentacoes
    def read_movimentacoes(self,processo):
        movimentacoes = []
        time.sleep(5)

        #clicar no link <a>     
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid')]/p[contains(@class,'lead')]/a").click()
        time.sleep(2)

        print 'Lendo Movimentacoes...1'
        moviments = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@id,'tableMovimentacoes1inst')]/tbody/tr")

        print "teste 0"
        for mov in moviments:
            data_hora = mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")
            data_hora = data_hora[0].text + " " + data_hora[1].text + ":00"
            data_mov = datetime.strptime(data_hora.strip(), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

            if processo['ultima_movimentacao'] <= data_mov:

                fase_movimentacao = mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text.encode('utf-8')

                mov = {'data': data_hora,
                    'faseMovimentacao': {'descricao': fase_movimentacao}
                    }

                if mov not in movimentacoes:
                    movimentacoes.append(mov)
                    # print mov
            else:
                print "teste3"
                return movimentacoes

        print "teste4"
        time.sleep(2)
        return movimentacoes
```

**Imagem do erro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> fase_movimentacao =
>   mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text.decode('utf-8')   File
>   "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   6-7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Pra evitar esses problemas de codificação recomendaria que usasse Python3+ ;) E o que você quer fazer é `decode('utf-8')` e não `encode()`

Comment: Não posso...O sistema esta configurado para usar o Python 2.7

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim podeira contribuir de forma mais consistente à resolução do problema ?

Comment: Acabei de editar meu comentário com uma sugestão, e acredito que sugerir uma outra versão seja consistente pro seu problema, visto que não estava claro na pergunta que não poderia trocar de versão. Tenta fazer o que sugeri, colocando `mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Na imagem, tem `decode()` mas na linha que mostrou tem `encode()`, qual está usando?

Comment: eu usei as duas e o problema persiste...em algumas perguntas aqui na steckoverflow usaram o decode para solucionar

Comment: eu recebo esta mensagem:  fase_movimentacao = mov.find_elements_by_xpath('td')[3].text.decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim onde encontro a documentação para webdriver do selenium ?

Comment: [Aqui](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) tem a doc

Comment: Fiz fase_movimentacao = mov.find_elements_by_xpath('td')[3].text.encode('ISO-8859-1') o erro persiste!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82369/discussion-between-tuxpilgrim-and-alexjosesilva).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é no Selenium, provavelmente o problema é no site que você esta tentando codificar ou decodificar para utf8, simplesmente podem haver caracteres não validos, que provavelmente na página que você tenta acessar devem estar sendo exibidos como:

- `�`
- Ou algo semelhante a `Ã©` (que representa o é) ou `Ã£` (que representa ã)

Talvez nem precise do `encode` em `mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text.encode('utf-8')` pois é provavel que o site já esteja em utf-8 também.

Geralmente site usam iso-8859-1/windows-1252 ou utf-8, creio que sua intenção seja converter para uma string, no caso provavelmente você poderia fazer isto:

```
fase_movimentacao = b"abc"

try:
    minha_str = fase_movimentacao.decode('utf-8')
except ValueError:
    minha_str = fase_movimentacao.decode('iso-8859-1')

print(minha_str)
```

No seu código seria algo como:

```
fase_movimentacao = mov.find_elements_by_xpath("td")[3].text

try:
    minha_str = fase_movimentacao.decode('utf-8')
except ValueError:
    minha_str = fase_movimentacao.decode('iso-8859-1')

mov = {'data': data_hora,
    'faseMovimentacao': {'descricao': minha_str }
}
```

Mas não posso afirmar se vai atender a tudo, ainda mais se tiver problemas de codificações no site de origem.